# Формат данных FVLN расшифровка

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, типы-данных

не могу понять как представляются данные. Пожалуйста подскажите. Есть число: 123456.78 в 16 виде оно представляется 0x02 0x15 0xCD 0x5B 0x07.

Формат FVLN: Беззнаковое число с точкой в байтовом формате варьируемой длины с порядком следования байтов от младшего к старшему. Первый байт определяет положение десятичной точки в числе.

Если правильно понял 0x02 при переводе в 10 дает число 2, получается отсчитываем от младшего 2 знака и получаем позицию точки. 0x15 поидее должен означать 78, 0хCD 56 и т.д. Но не получаются такие представления. Может кто объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

```
0x15 * 2560 +  
0xCD * 2561 +  
0x5B * 2562 +
0x07 * 2563
```

== `123456789`

Comment: если так, то почему запятая после 6 а не 7, или это из-за того что формат 8 байт должен быть и 9 просто выкидывается?

Comment: @dmig2006 Мне скорее кажется, что у вас ошибка в задании, и там `1234567.89` должно быть.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, пойду глубже копать)